# Why does print (absolute value) gives me back ASCII code in gdb

Tags: assembly, gdb, stack-frame

Here is my assambly code:

```
 0x0804841d <+0>:   push   %ebp
 0x0804841e <+1>:   mov    %esp,%ebp
 0x08048420 <+3>:   and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
 0x08048423 <+6>:   sub    $0x20,%esp
 0x08048426 <+9>:   movl   $0x8,0x1c(%esp)
 0x0804842e <+17>:  movl   $0x80484d0,(%esp)
 0x08048435 <+24>:  call   0x80482f0 <printf@plt>
=>0x0804843a <+29>: leave  
 0x0804843b <+30>:  ret
```

When i type `print 0x80484d0` it gives me back `$1 = 134513872` which I know stand for a string "asdfsfd".  So my question is that why does gdb gives back ASCII code instead of real string and how to change my option to make gdb display string.

And one more question: I know that `ESP` register looks at the bottom of the stack lets say its the addres A. `movl $0x80484d0,(%esp)` when this instruction occurs what happens with `esp`? I mean when some information is set to `esp` should not `esp` be change to A + size of x80484d0? to make the `esp` look at the bottom of the stack? [This image should make my question clearer](http://postimg.org/image/boyyqvaub/) . I know that i'm mistaken somewhere. Thank you.

Comment: _"`movl $0x80484d0,(%esp)` when this instruction occurs what happens with `esp`?"_. Nothing. You're writing to the memory pointed to by `esp`. `esp` itself isn't affected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`print` prints its arguments. Here, the argument is the integer `0x80484d0`, which in decimal is `134513872`.

If you want to print a string, you can use the eXamine command, asking for 1 string. E.g:

```
x/1s 0x80484d0
```

Or, you could also print an expression:

```
print (char *) 0x80484d0
```

Comment: It worked but why should i type x/1s instead of x/s the "1" just means the first byte of string right?

Comment: It means 1 object of whatever type follows, "s", for string. And `x/s` is equivalent to `x/1s`, since the default repeat count is 1.